# Making Table Have Same Look As It Does in Quirks Mode

Tags: css, quirks-mode

I am using the DOCTYPE below for my pages and it keeps the page in Quirks mode and my table looks like the one in the link below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

http://talkingsoccer.net/inquirks.jpg

When I change the doctype to either of the ones below, the pages are taken out of quirks mode and use IE8 Standards mode (I'm using IE8) as shown in the link below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> or <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

http://talkingsoccer.net/outofquirks.jpg

What can I do in CSS to make IE8 standards mode look like the table in Quirks mode (image shown at top link) and also in other major browses like Chrome, FireFox, IE8-IE12 and beyond?

Here is my code...

```
 <style>
   .link2 {  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;     
  font-weight: bold; color: #333333; text-decoration: none}
 </style>

 <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#B5CBE7">
 <tr> 
   <td><a href="http://www.example.com/" class="link2">Home Page</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
   <td><a href="http://www.example.com/affiliate.htm" class="link2">Affiliate Program</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/catalog.htm" class="link2">Order Catalog</a>   
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/privacy.htm" class="link2">Privacy Policy</a> 
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/status.htm" class="link2">Order Status</a></td>
  </tr>              
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/return.htm" class="link2">Return Policy</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/cybercart6.pl?action=order&
      merchant=mysite" class="link2">View Shopping Cart</a></td>

  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Do you just mean the cell padding. Like I have done in this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/aRnJ5/

Comment: You should specify which rendering features you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a div first and set the background that is your side image then create a table in that div margin-left the table for showing the bg image after that anchors, td, tr all the set padding and margin to 0 it will reduce the space between text and table border